# Syncing BuddyPress and WordPress profile fields

Tags: buddypress, sync, profiles

BuddyPress and WordPress store profile information in 2 separate locations, and there's a process to sync profile data between the 2 tables. However, this is pretty much limited (from how I'm reading the code) to a single name field.

What's the best way of adding other profile fields to this sync process (I'm particularly thinking of the description, and various contact fields) - looks like I'll need to create a function to hook into `xprofile_updated_profile` and `user_profile_update_errors` - is this right?

Is there an elegant way of establishing the mapping between WP `usermeta` and BP `xprofile_data`, or do I have to create the records representing profile fields in `xprofile_fields` manually?

Comment: As a note: I have used the [BP XProfile WordPress User Sync](http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/bp-xprofile-wp-user-sync) plugin or (parts; systematic) of its code in the past to do this.

Comment: It is worth noting that the sync feature in BuddyPress only synchronises the first name and lastname field with WP profile.

I had a need to create a custom WordPress profile and sync with BuddyPress xProfile and this extension worked flawlessly albeit a bit pricey considering you will have to buy it parent plugin. 
[BuddyPress Extended Profile Sync](http://profilepress.net/downloads/buddypress-extended-profile-sync/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest if you want to use BuddyPress always, just ignore/remove WordPress profile informations and you can: **Redirecting User to Their Buddypress Profile when They access their wordpress profile(wp-admin/profile.php)**:
http://buddydev.com/buddypress/playing-with-buddypress-and-wordpress-some-codes-for-the-site-admins/